# Whether to bother reporting non-significant three-way interaction?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, reporting

I'm just writing up a results section and the language is piling up a bit as it always does with interactions. Two of my two-ways are significant, one of the two-ways isn't, and the three-way isn't.

I don't have anything to hide, it's just getting a bit verbose:

"this changed the level of that (2-way interaction 1,  Fx,y=...P=...), but that effect wasn't also changed by changing the level of the other (3-way interaction, F....." etc.

Better just to say what I found in the two-way interactions, maybe leave the three-way out of it altogether?

Comment: I agree to just state that the three way interaction is not significant, and only describe the effects retained in the final model.